# How can I list files in CVS without an initial checkout?

Tags: svn, cvs, svn-checkout

How can I list files CVS without an initial checkout?

In subversion I can simply do "svn ls http://svn.svn.com" in CVS how can I do this?

For example I've got this CVS connection:

```
 pserver:anonymous@evocms.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/evocms
```

How can I list all files in it?

**UPDATE:**

I'm doing this:

```
c:\>set CVSROOT=pserver:anonymous@evocms.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/evocms
c:\>cvs -list ---> doesn't work, prints out the help screen
```

Comment: Hey, did you try franek's answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/889378/how-can-i-list-files-in-cvs-without-an-initial-checkout/2070969#2070969 It works flawlessly here!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If it's a one-off operation you don't need to set the `CVSROOT` environment variable. Just use the `-d` argument for ad-hoc repository specification.

If your version of CVS/CVSNT is not too old (to be exact you'd need either CVS 1.12.8 or higher or CVSNT) then, as others have said, **after having logged in**

```
cvs ls
```

should work just fine.

If your version of CVS/CVSNT does not support the `ls` command then you can try

```
cvs checkout -c
```

which will only dump the list of predefined [modules](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/Administrative-files.html#modules).

If your version of CVS/CVSNT is old enough you might get lucky with the following hack (does not work with more recent versions of CVSNT unless compatibility mode has been enabled on the server):

First check out the root of the repository to some temp location , so we have the necessary metadata:

```
cvs -d[your CVSROOT string] co -l -dTemp .
```

Then simulate an update (with directories) of that folder:

```
cd Temp
cvs -n up -d
```

This will emit (almost) the same output as an actual checkout without actually getting the files from the server.

If you're on Windows and using a fairly recent version of CVSNT as the client then `cvs ls` will actually automatically fall back to this mechanism when it detects a server that does not support `ls` itself.

---

Oh yes, and AFAICT there is no such thing as `cvs -list`. It's not even valid CVS command line syntax: `-list` would have to be a global argument rather than a command as it follows directly after the `cvs` and there is no actual command specified. But then again, all multi-letter arguments (such as `--help`) would have to start with a double dash, e.g. `cvs --version`. Were you all maybe thinking of `cvs list` which would be a mere alias for `cvs ls`?

Comment: I'm using this one : http://ftp.gnu.org/non-gnu/cvs/binary/stable/x86-woe/cvs-1-11-14.zip is this the wrong one? Maybe that's why it's not working.

Comment: Judging by the version number I think that one should be fine. I'm using CVSNT 2.5.04 myself (which unfortunately does no longer appear to be available from the original source - it has by now been superceded by some semi-commercial product). Also, I assume that that is what you're using on the client rather than on the server?

You haven't written anything yet about what happens when you do cvs ls (after having set the CVSROOT and logged in).

Comment: correction: CVSNT 2.5.04 is still available for free download from http://cvsnt.org - it's just that they made the download link somewhat obscure - search near the right hand border of the page - note that the user data fields are all voluntary

Comment: Ok, another correction: CVS 1.11.x does indeed not support the ls command. You'd need at least CVS 1.12.x for that. Also note that even for CVS 1.11.x the download link you posted is for a very old version (1.11.14 - the latest would have been 1.11.23)

Comment: That didn't work. Same results. I'm trying to download this CVSNT but all of the links leads to client-trial version. Yes I only use the client.

Comment: What exactly didn't work? CVS 1.12.x ? Note that a (slightly) older CVSNT client is also included with both the WinCvs and TortoiseCVS frontends, either of which I strongly recommend anyway if you seriously intend to work with CVS from Windows. Both also have a graphical UI for the "cvs ls" command.

Comment: When I have tried to perform the 'cvs ls' command, I get an error saying it is unsupported by the server.

Using the 'cvs -d[your CVSROOT string] co -l -dTemp .
' in conjuction with 'cvs -n up -d' worked well enough for what I needed.

Answer (score 16):

```
cvs -d $CVSROOT rls
```

hope this helps (cvs ver. 1.12.13)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do a [login](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/login.html) first, like this:

> cvs -d :pserver:anonymous@evocms.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/evocms login

Then, as others have said, use the [*ls* command](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/ls.html).

For background, see a [discussion of remote repositories](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/Remote-repositories.html)

Comment: now I see, I think the problem is in my computer where -d doesn't set the environment variable, don't know why.

Comment: I'm doing this : 
"c:\>set cvsroot=:pserver:anonymous:@evocms.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/evocms"
"c:\>cvs -list" ->> doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try cvs -list pserver:anonymous@evocms.cvs.sourceforge.net:/cvsroot/evocms

Answer (score 3):

This is what I use. msolorzano is my login, and password, and "Deployer" is the module:

```
cvs -d :pserver:msolorzano:password@gtess-cvs:/cvsdata/data1 rlog -R Deployer
```

...as a matter of fact, you can vet a cvs list of files in a "clean way" if you are executing commands in a UNIX/Linux environment, like this:

```
cvs -d :pserver:msolorzano:password@gtess-cvs:/cvsdata/data1 rlog Deployer | grep  ',v' | sed 's/RCS file: //g' | sed s/,v//g
```

Answer (score 2):

there is a similiar command in cvs

Usage: cvs ls
<strike>cvs -list to list modules, ls to list contents of modules.</strike>

EDIT: They are right, the commands list and ls are the same, I´m sorry for that.

well I don´t really see how to list a cvs dir without actually checking it out.
Does the repo your are trying to access have a cvsweb access?

Comment: Hum, try setting the CVSROOT parameter as an enviroment variable, thats what I use, so you don´t have to pass the entire string with every command. I never tried with ls though.

Comment: I've tried that as well somehow that doesn't work either, see my update in the question. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: What version of CVS are you using? The -list parameter doesn't exist in any of the versions I know of.

Comment: see discussion on simon622's answer. The command is actually "cvs list" (without the dash) and is a mere alias for "cvs ls", i.e. there should be absolutely no difference between "cvs list" and "cvs ls".

Answer (score 0):

[see cvs commands](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/ls.html)

for example;

```
cvs list
```

will list all modules in CVS server

Comment: People, why do you keep posting this? This parameter does not exist! It's not even valid CVS command syntax to begin with!

Comment: It exists as a command instead of an argument, using;  "cvs list" WILL list the modules on a server.

Comment: Yeah, OK, I already guessed that by now. This would work because "list" is just a synonym of "ls". See "cvs --help-synonyms"

Answer (score 0):

All,

Here is a comprehensive way to do it:

1. Fire up the command prompt
2. Copy this cvs -d CVSROOT login (or, whatever your corresponding CVSROOT is)
3. Type in your password and press enter when prompted. It may take a while, but after that is done, a new prompt will be available.
4. Type in cvs –d cvs -d CVSROOT ls
5. BAM! There's your listing

Keep in mind, if you don't have CVSROOT defined, you can just copy and paste your own CVSROOT here.

Comment: I can't get this to work with a CVSROOT containing the ':ext:' protocol. CVS complains that only 'pserver' is accepted, I don't appear to have pserver access here at work :-(

Answer (score 0):

`cvs -d [CVS_ROOT] rlog {module_name}`

Comment: `rlog`, like `log`, lists revisions, not files.