# cvs checkout -c doesn't show all modules

Tags: version-control, module, cvs, cat, vcs-checkout

I have a module in my repository. Let's call it `module1`.

If I just checkout it, it's alright, it shows up in my machine and I can work on it.

There's a parameter in checkout command named `-c` - according to help, '"cat" the module database.'.

But when I run this command

```
cvs co -c
```

The module isn't showing up. Why? Is there a cache file, something in my machine that needs to be updated, flushes or something? `module1` **exists**, but doesn't show up when `cvs co -c` is called. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cvs checkout -c` simply dumps the contents of the $CVSROOT/modules file in alphabetical order minus the comments. This file has to be maintained manually. You can find information about it in the [CVS manual](http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/Administrative-files.html#modules).

If you want to list *physical* modules (as opposed to the virtual modules defined in the `modules` file, then what you're looking for is the `cvs ls` command. Note however that this command is only supported as of CVS 1.12.x as well as by most versions of CVSNT.

An alternative approach for listing physical modules that also works with older versions of CVS/CVSNT is described in this answer:

[How can I list files in CVS without an initial checkout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889378/how-can-i-list-files-in-cvs-without-an-initial-checkout/896764#896764)