# How can I list all modules in a CVS repository?

Tags: cvs

Is there a command that returns a list of module names contained within a CVS repository?

Being a newbie to CVS, I imagine that there should be something along the lines of

```
cvs -d /usr/local/cvs listmodules
```

What should I substitute `listmodules` with to get a list of all modules within the CVS repository?

---

To address Dewfy's comment, `cvs --help-commands` returns the following:

> ```
>     add          Add a new file/directory to the repository
>     admin        Administration front end for rcs
>     annotate     Show last revision where each line was modified
>     checkout     Checkout sources for editing
>     commit       Check files into the repository
>     diff         Show differences between revisions
>     edit         Get ready to edit a watched file
>     editors      See who is editing a watched file
>     export       Export sources from CVS, similar to checkout
>     history      Show repository access history
>     import       Import sources into CVS, using vendor branches
>     init         Create a CVS repository if it doesn't exist
>     kserver      Kerberos server mode
>     log          Print out history information for files
>     login        Prompt for password for authenticating server
>     logout       Removes entry in .cvspass for remote repository
>     pserver      Password server mode
>     rannotate    Show last revision where each line of module was modified
>     rdiff        Create 'patch' format diffs between releases
>     release      Indicate that a Module is no longer in use
>     remove       Remove an entry from the repository
>     rlog         Print out history information for a module
>     rtag         Add a symbolic tag to a module
>     server       Server mode
>     status       Display status information on checked out files
>     tag          Add a symbolic tag to checked out version of files
>     unedit       Undo an edit command
>     update       Bring work tree in sync with repository
>     version      Show current CVS version(s)
>     watch        Set watches
>     watchers     See who is watching a file
> ```

The CVS version is **1.11.22**.

Comment: I actually want to run in `:ext:` mode, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As already described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889378/how-can-i-list-files-in-cvs-without-an-initial-checkout/896764#896764) there are basically three ways to go about this. Which one suits your situation depends firstly on what versions of CVS you are using on both client and server and secondly on your definition of "modules".

1. If you are referring to modules as they were originally thought of by the CVS authors, i.e. as entries in the `CVSROOT/modules` file then `cvs co -c` or `cvs co -s` will give you that, the only difference between the two being that the latter will sort the output by "status". You can read about the modules file here: http://cvsbook.red-bean.com/cvsbook.html#modules
2. If you are using at least CVS 1.12.8 or CVSNT and your idea of modules corresponds more to actual directories inside the repository, then `cvs ls` should be what you want.
3. Finally, if you are indeed after a remote directory listing but your server is running an older version of CVS, then there's the trick of first performing a "fake" checkout and then simulating a recursive update:

   cvs -d [CVSROOT] co -l .

   cvs -n up -d

Answer (score 1):

Use following:

```
 cvs -d /usr/local/cvs ls
```

According to this http://www.cvsnt.org/manual/html/ls.html there are synonyms: dir,list,rls

And of course don't forgive to review all available commands by:

```
cvs --help-commands
```

Comment: `ls` and its synonyms aren't recognized as a command. See my comment in [Mikel's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437885/how-can-i-list-all-modules-in-a-cvs-repository/3437915#3437915)

Comment: @Zaid - could you please execute : cvs --help-commands
and enlist the result

Comment: @Zaid - so pity, it looks like you use some brief cvs, then the simplest way is execute 'export' command - that in minimal affect local file system.
Also may be helpful in some case option -l (don't use recursion)

Answer (score 0):

You can run

```
cvs ls
```

to list the tree in CVS >= 1.11 (see cvs --version), or run

```
cvs checkout CVSROOT/modules
```

to see the module configuration file.

Comment: `ls` isn't recognized. Neither are the synonyms [suggested by Dewfy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437885/how-can-i-list-all-modules-in-a-cvs-repository/3437948#3437948)

Comment: Yeah, you need CVS 1.11 or above.  I think it's required on both the client and server.

But the modules file should be available even with older versions.

Comment: There is no modules file :/.