# Can I configure review-board to access CVS through mount

Tags: windows, cvs, review-board

I have CVS installed on a Windows 7 computer with pserver and it works fine. I have Review Board installed on a Linux computer. I tried to add the repository to RB, I copied the usual string ":pserver:user@cvsmachine:/myrepo" but no luck. I tried 50 different variations, including SSH with :ext: and nothing works.  Always I get

```
A repository was not found at the specified path.
```

So I decided instead to just create a mount point on the Linux computer to the cvsroot directory on the Windows computer. Then I use the mount point path to add the repository to RB.

This works! Only I have to set the "name" of the repo in RB to match the name in the "CVS/root" on the client. Use **post-review -d** to see the desired name.

**My question is**: it is safe to do this? Is this going to corrupt my repository? I think RB only reads the repo, right?

Comment: You should make the mount read-only if you are worried about corrupting the repository. We have RB set up at work with a repository mounted in a similar way and have had no problems, but that's just one person's anecdotal evidence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've since learned that using CVS via shared drive is common practice, and CVS seems to be able to checkout fine with read-only access.

The reason that review-board fails with pserver is that it REQUIRES you to have a file called CVSROOT/modules. If your repository doesn't have that file (and ours doesn't), it chokes.

imo, this is a bug in RB, and the most reliable way to get a list of modules is with "cvs co -l" and "cvs -n up -d", as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/889378/how-can-i-list-files-in-cvs-without-an-initial-checkout/896764#896764).